# Search by key, order by value

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is a sample of my Firebase data:

[image: data]

I need to be able to search userFavorites for a given user (here, afaapy...) and return the results ordered by the values (timestamps) to get all the user's favorites in order of the date added to the database.

I can search by key as follows, and retrieve all favorites for the given user:

```
databaseRef.child("userFavorites").queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: user.uid).observe(...)
```

But these favorties are ordered by their keys. If I try to order by value as follows, I get "Cannot use multiple queryOrderedBy calls!":

```
databaseRef.child("userFavorites").queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: user.uid).queryOrderedByValue().observe(...)
```

How can I retrieve the favorites for a given user sorted by their value?

Second question: is there an easier way to retrieve data in the order it was added to the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't order the same ref multiple times as documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data)

When you use a `order` or a `filter` method, it returns  a [Query Interface](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Query#ref). See it as a filtered reference containing only a subset of the original data. It means that

```js
databaseRef.child("userFavorites").orderByKey().equalTo(user.uid)
```

will not return `userFavorite/${user.uid}` but `userFavorite` filtered to show only the `user.uid` entry. You can see it by doing

```js
databaseRef.child("userFavorites").orderByKey().equalTo(user.uid).ref.key
```

That should return `'userFavorites'`

In your case, I see two options:

Keep going with `orderByKey().equalTo()` and sort the results yourself

Or use directly `child()` to get the user, then sort via Firebase (and don't forget to use the Firebase's `snapshot.forEach` to be sure you get the data in the query order):

```js
databaseRef.child(`userFavorites/${user.uid}`).orderByValue().once('value', (snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        snapshot.forEach((child) => {
          console.log(`${child.key}: ${child.val()}`)
        })
      }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's pretty obvious now that I think about it - not sure why I didn't think to use child() in the first place.